# Gatling wrapper shell script fails with ClassNotFound

Tags: bash, gatling

I am trying to script a gatling run on localhost. I wrote a shell script for that.

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

do_run() {
    local instance="$1"
    local users="$2"
    local endpoint="$3"
    local token="$4"

    echo "Instance: $instance"
    echo "Users: $users"
    echo "Endpoint: $endpoint"
    echo "Token: $token"

    # Test that the endpoint works
    curl -s -X POST -H "content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" \
    $endpoint \
    -d '{"dataframe_records": [{"id": 0}]}'

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'Smoke test successful'
    else
        echo 'Smoke test failed'
        return
    fi

    echo

    RESULTS_FOLDER="${HOME}/results/${instance}/${users}"
    echo "Remove results folder $RESULTS_FOLDER"
    rm -rf $RESULTS_FOLDER

    echo "Create results folder $RESULTS_FOLDER"
    mkdir -p $RESULTS_FOLDER

    echo
    echo "Simulation Command Line:"
    echo

    echo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64 \
    ${HOME}/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.10.3/bin/gatling.sh \
    -rm local \
    -s "\"OnlineTableSimulation\"" \
    -sf "/home/ec2-user/perf-test/simulation" \
    -rf "\"${HOME}/results/${instance}/${users}\"" \
    -erjo "\"-Dconcurrent_users=${users} -Dendpoint=${endpoint} -Dtoken=${token}\"" \
    -rd "\"${instance} instance, ${users} concurrent users\""

    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64

    echo
    echo "Running simulation:"
    echo
    
    ${HOME}/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.10.3/bin/gatling.sh \
    -erjo "\"-Dconcurrent_users=${users} -Dendpoint=${endpoint} -Dtoken=${token}\"" \
    -rm local \
    -s "\"OnlineTableSimulation\"" \
    -sf "/home/ec2-user/perf-test/simulation" \
    -rf "\"${HOME}/results/${instance}/${users}\"" \
    -rd "\"${instance} instance, ${users} concurrent users\""

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'stress test successful'
    else
        echo 'stress test failed'
        return
    fi
}

SMALL_ENDPOINT="https://contoso.com"
MEDIUM_ENDPOINT="https://contoso.com"
LARGE_ENDPOINT="https://contoso.com"


SMALL_TOKEN="token"

MEDIUM_TOKEN="token"

LARGE_TOKEN="token"

for i in {1000,2000,4000};
do
    do_run "medium" $i $MEDIUM_ENDPOINT $MEDIUM_TOKEN
done

for i in {1000,2000,4000};
do
    do_run "large" $i $LARGE_ENDPOINT $LARGE_TOKEN
done
```

This is the `gatling.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Copyright 2011-2023 GatlingCorp (http://gatling.io)
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    JAVA="$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java
else
    JAVA=java
fi

OLDDIR=$(pwd)
BIN_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
cd "${BIN_DIR}/.." && DEFAULT_GATLING_HOME=$(pwd) && cd "${OLDDIR}"

GATLING_HOME="${GATLING_HOME:=${DEFAULT_GATLING_HOME}}"

JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Xms32M -Xmx128M"

# Setup classpath
CLASSPATH="$GATLING_HOME/lib/*"

echo "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$CLASSPATH" io.gatling.bundle.GatlingCLI "$@"
"$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$CLASSPATH" io.gatling.bundle.GatlingCLI "$@"
```

When I run my script, I get the following error:

```
GATLING_HOME is set to /home/ec2-user/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.10.3
20:00:35.108 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - [zinc] IncrementalCompile -----------
20:00:35.116 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - IncrementalCompile.incrementalCompile
20:00:35.121 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - previous = Stamps for: 1 products, 1 sources, 2 libraries
20:00:35.122 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - current source = Set(/home/ec2-user/perf-test/simulation/com/contoso/simulation/OnlineTableSimulation.java)
20:00:35.163 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - > initialChanges = InitialChanges(Changes(added = Set(), removed = Set(), changed = Set(), unmodified = ...),Set(),Set(),API Changes: Set())
20:00:35.167 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - No changes
20:00:35.256 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation successful
Error: Could not find or load main class "-Dconcurrent_users=4000
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "-Dconcurrent_users=4000
```

For some reason, it is messing the `-erjo` parameter and considering that as part of the simulation class. Even though I passed in the simulation class using `-s` parameter separately.

However, if I copy the command line printed by the shell script, and run it separately in the terminal, it works fine.

I tried moving the `-erjo` option as the first and last argument to the script, but those didnt work either.

I think I am messing the shell script somehow. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The literal backslashed quotes around the `-erjo` arguments look weird, but we can't know what it expects or what it's doing internally. Try dropping the `\"`s on both sides.

Comment: ...generally, the only time those quotes are actually correct would be if the script you're calling is concatenating arguments into something it `eval`s. That's horrible practice, but relatively common in the Java world (Tomcat did it in the early days, and a lot of other projects took Tomcat's wrapper scripts as a "this is how we build a JVM wrapper in shell" example to copy from, as horrid as they were).

Comment: That is all to say -- we'd need to know the contents of the `gatling.sh` script to speak to this; but _if_ your usage is correct, that script is awful (in a way that many other JVM-ecosystem shell scripts are also awful, unfortunately).

Comment: Where I'd suggest starting to have an on-topic Stack Overflow question, though, is to get into the contents of that script and try to build a [mre] that provides a self-contained demonstration that includes both the essential elements of how you're calling it, _and_ the essential elements of what it's doing with the arguments it's passed. ("Essential" meaning, among other things, eliminating duplication; no need to mishandle N arguments the same way if one suffices to reproduce the case).

Comment: (BTW, there are several issues in your code that http://shellcheck.net/ will flag warnings for; I'd suggest correcting them, if for no other reason to have fewer distractors or places where details of the data being handled needs to be understood to evaluate relevance of potential corner cases).

Comment: ...for the purposes of building a [mre], btw, you should find `set -x` to enable debug logging, and `bash -x script ...` to run a script with debug logging (`sh -x script ...` if its shebang is `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/usr/bin/bash`) useful tools, so you can compare the actual and expected behavior and ask a question more focused on a specific place where they diverge.

Comment: I suspect you added the extra escaped quotes to make it look right when you `echo` it -- **don't do this!** `echo` shows you the post-parsing version of a command (after quotes, escapes, etc have been applied *and removed*), but what you need to enter in the script is the *pre-parsing* version of a command. They're different, so if you try to make them match it's not going to work.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy and others. I added the gatling.sh script that i am calling.

Comment: Okay. No `eval` in that script, so the literal quotes you're adding aren't consumed by the shell interpreter at all; instead, they're just passed straight through to the JVM; meaning, they're correct _if and only if_ the Java program being invoked _expects_ literal quotes in its command-line arguments.

Comment: BTW, is there any specific documentation that _told_ you to add the literal quotes, instead of using syntactic quotes only? Where did the idea to do that come from in the first place?

Comment: ...if you read https://docs.gatling.io/guides/passing-parameters/, for example, they _only_ have syntactic quotes in their sample code using the `-erjo` parameter -- no literal ones at all.

Comment: ...I suspect they might be doing something as simple as splitting the argument on spaces, checking whether the first argument of each word that results from that split is a `-`, treating it as a parameter if it is, and treating it as a class name if it's not. If that's the case, adding a literal `"` before the `-` would prevent the detection of `"-D...` as an option.

Comment: if I dont add those quotes then it gets confused...

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin/java -Xms32M -Xmx128M -cp "/home/ec2-user/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.10.3/lib/*" io.gatling.bundle.GatlingCLI -rm local -s "com.zillow.simulation.OnlineTableSimulation" -sf /home/ec2-user/perf-test/simulation -rf "/home/ec2-user/results/large/4000" -rd "large instance, 4000 concurrent users" -erjo -Dconcurrent_users=4000 -Dendpoint=https://contoso.com -Dtoken=TOKEN
```
Gives
```
Warning: Unknown option -Dendpoint=https://conto -Dtoken=token```

Comment: That's less confused than your current code is.

Comment: That said, in the comment above you took out _both_ the literal quotes and the syntactic quotes. Remove only the literal quotes, keep the syntactic ones.

Comment: That is, you should be passing `-erjo "-Dconcurrent_users=4000 -Dendpoint=contoso.com -Dtoken=TOKEN"` -- the quotes there are shell syntax, they're not part of the literal arguments. Whereas `\"` is a literal quote: the backslash tells the shell that it should be evaluating to `"` _as part of the string itself_, instead of treating `"` as a character that starts or ends a double-quoted (section of a) string.

Comment: (similarly, in `'"hello"'`, the `'`s are syntactic and the `"`s are literal even without a backslash, because syntactic single quotes make every character in them _until the next single quote_ be literal).

Comment: In keeping with what @GordonDavisson said -- if you want to log what command would be run by a set of arguments, **do not ever use `echo` for that**. Use `set -x` to tell the shell to log the commands it's running; or if you want something to just log a command without running it, try this function: `log_cmd() { printf '%q ' "$@" && echo; }`

Comment: I think there is something in the token that is confusing the bash parser.

Comment: Thanks for the links to shellcheck.net. Never knew about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257043/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-feroze).

Comment: Don't use all upper case for non-exported variables. For all we know your problem could just be you clobbering some environment variable(s).